# How do I refer to the "typeof T" in a generic function?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

```js
function isSameOrSubclass<T>(target:any,reference:typeof T):target is T
{
    const   targetIsReference   = target===reference,
            targetIsTruthy      = target&&true,
            targetHasPrototype  = "prototype" in target,
            targetIsSubclass    = targetIsTruthy&&targetHasPrototype&&(target.prototype instanceof reference)
    return targetIsReference||targetIsSubclass;
}
```

Compiler fails with the following error:

> TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Substituting `typeof T` with `new()=>T` allows compilation, but disallows this:

```js
isSameOrSubclass<Class>(foo,Class)
```

because

> Argument of type 'typeof Class' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Class'.

Comment: Cannot replicate: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAE8DOBlAhgWwKYDyATpuAEbQA2266APACoB8AFLNsQOb6wBcKbJACeAGhTF8ofJJj4BkfAHcUrAJQoAvMxSM1Ajt15p0ulAG9gKaymjJ0sG4Z6wAkugBKUmfjk3NKM7GmiES3rLQ+KJWNrGxQW7ojMTgsAAWwnFagZwuKABk+YEpUTFZ8bm8ABK0AArEiLCNwgAO+NYBAEQtDU2wrfidaKgJ0eVxCe5klDR0sQGTSSnpmYU5RrA16PWNzW0FReyVsAB0Pbv9+-CQDkKRiKBh0hH4aiCxkrDgxCPH7l7PXyRFAAHxB6xcUwo1Fo6AA3MAAL4gGFzMhtYio0zmZFYlAAYVmpnwAA9YL4ACamdEyPE4lH2RBUfAnKiILisDA4AgkaZY1iE2HiGmYolqNRAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` needs to be constrained to `extends new() => {}` ***or similar** and then used directly (not via `typeof`), like this:

```
function isSameOrSubclass<T extends new() => {}>(target:any,reference: T):target is T
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
{
    const   targetIsReference   = target===reference,
            targetIsTruthy      = target&&true,
            targetHasPrototype  = "prototype" in target,
            targetIsSubclass    = targetIsTruthy&&targetHasPrototype&&(target.prototype instanceof reference)
    return targetIsReference||targetIsSubclass;
}
```

***or similar**: the type `new() => {}` refers to classes with zero-argument constructor functions. Consequently, to accept classes with one-or-more-arguments constructors, a different type is necessary. i.e. `new(...args) => {}`

And then you use it without any explicit type parameter, like this:

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}
class Unrelated {}
console.log(isSameOrSubclass(Child, Parent));      // true
console.log(isSameOrSubclass(Parent, Parent));     // true
console.log(isSameOrSubclass(Parent, Unrelated));  // false
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgZQIYFsCmB5AJzRACMIAbDFFAHgBVEcAPKHMAExUTBwHcAKAJSIAvAD5EAbwC+Y-lAwEA5jigAuDGACeAGgI5gOfZBxrEdQWoXLVyLnQBQkh4leIICFFDfWVUAJIoAEoGRmwQOG4iiL6qIvH6hsYROi5u6emxASh0BCBQABZaGaIxin4AZBVQeTipJSVZABJUAAoEcFCdWgAOkaUARD0dXVC9OAPISFn1DZnlqoHEZJTU6dFZgbn5RVXNbSPdfVXyC1AAdMOdR5EwYF6aEXDAiIlhJoJprvpQIATTZ0CISS4RwAB8wZt0KQKFQUABuBzSBwOWFrVqKNjeGSo1ZcADCBRg5HYjBYbE4iAxxmxyLRXAAqmB9JRWKScR57nByDhzuQ4Ep+KhMLhCMt6fxCcT2DoqZiwFBBIJEZyUNzefzBcLsPgiDC8fxqVjZUaFUqVZ51XyBUL0Dqxfq4Yb5VBZUyWRg2eaHEA)

Comment: I had trouble at first because `isSameOrSubclass(someObject,SomeClass)` failed with `TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof SomeClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new()=>{}'`. Then I realized the problem now was that the constructor of SomeClass specifies arguments. So I changed `<T extends new()=>{}>` to `T extends new(...args:any)=>{}` and it works. Comments? I'll accept your answer and emphasize "or similar".